# GCC error, bad code or gcc is good compiler

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have this code:

```
int *b;
b = 50;
printf("Pointer point to address: %p and also point to this value: %d", b, *b);
return 0
```

I got this error:
main.c:6:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

timeout: the monitored command dumped core

sh: line 1: 47524 Segmentation fault      timeout 10s main

I wanna print value from fifty byte of memory.

**Is my code right or will compiler do it work.**

Comment: The compiler is always right. The compiler gave you a warning. You ignored it and look what happened. The warning is actually pretty obvious and something most C programmer will recognise...

Comment: I strongly suggest you go thru any basic c tutorial about pointers and references.

Comment: `50` is probably not a good (hard coded) pointer value. Please try `int a = 50; int *b = &a; ...`

Comment: I think I get some value from memory, something like leak.

Comment: You have tried to read memory address `50` which probably does not belong to you, hence the segfault. The compiler objected because `50` is an integer value, not a pointer value, hence the warning.

Comment: Listen to Weather Vane - that will fix your issue.   You cannot assign 50 to b as you have written it.  b is expecting the address of another integer not an integer value itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running the program on a recent OS like Linux, Mac or Windows, 50 will no be the bytes located at the address 50 in your physical memory ; that's an address in a virtual space.

Then your process (program) has only access to a very limited range in that virtual space, which 50 is unlikely to be from ; in that case the OS protects the illegal access and stops your process (segfault) ; anyway you could even get a result that may or may not be the correct one, this is called *undefined behavior*, and you better not rely in this case on a apparently working executable.

To access directly the physical memory, you either need to build a kernel module, or boot from a DOS-like OS, for instance.

> main.c:6:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

This being said, you need to cast `50` as a `int *` to clear the warning.

```
b = (int *)50;
```